# Multiple indexes in list comprehension

Tags: python

I need to write a function that will return list of strings with even indices. I have a problem with finding a way to check indices inside list comprehension, I tried index() but it gives me the index of a first instance and the list is not composed of unique characters.

This is what I got so far:

```
def even_chars(st):
print(st)
if len(st) < 2 or len(st) > 100:
    return 'invalid string'
else:
    return [s for s in st if st.index(s) % 2 != 0]
```

I was thinking about putting another argument inside index() since it makes it possible to start search from given index but there's no way ti increment it for every s. Any hint? Maybe there's some built in function I'm missing?

Comment: could you provide input / expected output as well?

Comment: Example input:

`z6Wz+*Z]T&Ya;~B(3Vwsglzn}~!j6&GZ<H1G.5)kRa[]~?))9?P;<Nz/nCx~\%u:4xORZqP6S`~$R\}HK/V\[dY`

Expected output:

`['6', 'z', '*', ']', '&', 'a', '~', '(', 'V', 's', 'l', 'n', '}', '!', '6', 'G', '<', '1', '.', ')', '\x0b', 'a', ']', '?', ')', '?', ';', 'N', '/', 'C', '~', '%', ':', 'x', 'R', 'q', '6', '\x0b', '~', 'R', '}', 'K', 'V', '\\', 'd']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enumerate for that, essentially returning the number of the current iteration:

```
[s for i, s in enumerate(st) if i % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: Super cool, that worked. I din't know we can use commas inside list comprehension like that. So "s for i,s in enumerate() if" means create a list of number-string pairs and for each number tied to a string that meets rquirements put that number on a list, am I getting it right? That's soo useful, thanks!

Comment: Yes, exactly only that "put that number on a list" instead is: "put that string on a list". You can do the same with your function as well. A function can have multiply return values you would specify it like this: return a, b and then get these values like this: a, b = func()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#The original string
st = "this is a string"

# Converted into a list
st_list = list(st)

# Print all the elements at even positions
print(st_list[1::2])
```

This way you don't need a function.

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to do it without function, I;m looking for help with figuring it on my own or at least my way. Im really new to coding so I need to figure some things more or less on my own but thanks, I didn't know about [x::y] syntax.

Comment: I was not trying to correct you (sorry if it did). I just wanted to give a different approach to the question, a bit less intricate. I also discovered the [::] syntax recently and it's very handy, in my opinion.